# Code Analysis | Suppress namespace, folder or file

Tags: code-analysis, suppression

How can I suppress a namespace, folder(with multiple files) or file from Code Analysis?

None of the existing stack overflow answers seem to have a direct answer to this question.

Existing possibilities:
- Inline suppression of method

Comment: I do not know about the Code Analysis. But the opportunity to exclude files or folders implemented in CppCat. Let's try it.